# Position D3 SVG Canvas x/y and Zoom Level On Load

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create an organization chart. I've got the data loading fine and have figured out how to make the canvas move by dragging the mouse as well a zoom with the mouse wheel.

My problem is that the org chart is rather large so when the document first loads the root node is out of the browser's view area and the zoom level is set fairly high.

I need to figure out how to set the viewable area of the canvas around the first node and set the initial zoom level to 100%.

Comment: If you're using the zoom behaviour, you can set translate/scale to the values you like on load.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am able to set the zoom but my problem is still adjusting the viewable area.

Comment: What do you mean by "viewable area"?

Comment: The first few lines of my rendered svg is: `<svg id="svg-canvas" class="main-svg">
<defs>
<g class="svg_g">
<g id="node-0" class="node type-NN ne-O" transform="translate(6516.395872592926,18)">` but node-0 appears off the screen so to see it you have to mouse click over or zoom way out and then zoom way in. I need to figure out how to make the document load with node-0 being centered at the top.

Comment: What's setting the initial translation? Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: I'm adapting from the code here: http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/home I would post it but the libraries and files are pretty extensive. They are using https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre

Comment: Well, if you can select the root node and its coordinates, you could translate accordingly -- something like `d3.select(".svg_g").attr("transform", d3.select("#node-0").attr("transform") + "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution thanks to @Lars Kotthoff.

I retrieved the root node's x value from it's translate attribute (i.e. translate(x,y)) and then took the browser's width / 2 - the x value. I applied this value to the parent group's translate attribute which centers the document around the root node.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var node0 = d3.select("#node-0");
var translate = parseTranslate(node0.attr("transform"));
var translateX = translate.x - (windowWidth / 2);
var svgGroup = d3.select("#svg_g");
svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(-" + translateX + ",22) scale(1)"); // with 20 y padding
```

**NOTE:** Because I'm new to SVG and D3 I am still not sure how to get just the "x" value of a node's translate attribute so I created a function that parses the translate attribute with regex. **I'm sure there is a better way of getting this value so if anyone wants to update my answer or add a comment for future readers that would increase the value of this question.**

The function I created is:

```
function parseTranslate(str) {
var translate = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scale: 0
}

var pattern = /\((.+?)\)/g;
var matches = [];

while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

if (matches.length) {
    if (matches.length == 1) {
        if (matches[0].indexOf(",") > -1) {
            var p = matches[0].split(',');
            translate.x = p[0];
            translate.y = p[1];
        } else {
            translate.scale = matches[0];
        }
    } else if (matches.length == 2) {
        var p = matches[0].split(',');
        translate.x = p[0];
        translate.y = p[1];
        translate.scale = matches[1];
    }
}
return translate;
}
```

I'm also using jQuery in my project to get the width of the browser (ex: $(window).width();)